# Creating multiple irc connections

Tags: python-3.x

Please tell me which way to look. The task is to create multiple IRC connections. A user comes to the site, we create a dedicated IRC connection for him. I was initially thinking about threads and multiprocesses, but I am not sure if I can fit 2000-3000 IRC connections into them. So I am starting to think about creation of some CI system, should I create one machine for every 100 threads or am I overdoing it and 2000-3000 isn't a big number?

Comment: Well, you can try it and tell us if your server can handle such charge. I'm amazed there's still thousands of IRC users nowadays, I thought Discord definitely burried it

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something then, if there are 2000 channels connected in one IRC. Wouldn't it be more convenient for each channel to have its own IRC?